# Cannot open shared object file when run Linux project through Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am building and running C++ project in WSL Ubuntu 20.04 through Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 10.

I included all relevant paths to project's `Additional Library Search Path` and all `.so` files to `Library Dependecies` and was able to build the project in VS.

However, when I run in VS I get `error while loading shared libraries: xxx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. The missing `.so` is located at `/home/myuser/my_ws/install/lib` (**DIR**). If I copy manually that library from **DIR** to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` then it can find it.

I tried adding that `.so` to `Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Additional Symbol Search Paths`, but it didn't help

[image]

**UPDATE**

I tried adding `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/myuser/my_ws/install/lib` to `Pre-Launch Command` as suggested by @Sam Varshavchik and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To load a `.so` library at runtime, one of the following three conditions must be met.

1. The `.so` library must be located in one of the default system library locations, like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`, or various subdirectories there. Additional default system library locations are listed in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.
2. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable must be set, accordingly, before running the executable that attempts to load the `.so` file.
3. The executable must be linked with the `-rpath` or `-R` linker flag, specifying the directory to add to the search path, at runtime.

You can decide which approach will work the best for you, and proceed accordingly. See the `ld.so(8)` manual page for a complete description of the shared library loading process, and additional options.

Comment: I tried setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and it worked (see my update in the post). But, I also want it to work with `-rpath` or `-R` linker flag. I'm not sure how to add this in Visual Studio. I tried adding `-R /usr...` in `Linker -> Command Line` but I get `g++ : error : unrecognized command line option ‘-R’` error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I wrote "linker flag". This is a linker option. It needs to be forwarded by `gcc` using `-Wl`. See the `gcc` and `ld` man pages.